# chrome extension for changing layout not working in facebook

Tags: facebook, layout

I just want a simple, light, couple of lines extension that hides the div #appsNav in facebook. As far as I can see #appsNav is holding some useless information for me like games or games feed. Its annoying.

Now I wrote my manifest.json like this:

```
{
 "manifest_version": 2,

 "name": "Hide sideNav",
 "description": "Hide facebook sideNav.",
 "version": "1.0",

 "content_scripts": [
 {
  "matches": ["http://facebook.com/*", "https://facebook.com/*"],
  "css": ["mycss.css"],
  "js": ["jquery.js", "myscript.js"]
 }
  ],

"permissions": [
"http://facebook.com/*", "https://facebook.com/*"
 ]

}
```

My myscript.js like this:

```
$("#appsNav").hide();
```

And even a css file to display:none;

```
#appsNav{
display:none;
}
```

When I make a dummy page it all works (so I guess the code is written right), but when I try doing it for Facebook, nothing happens. Is there something wrong with my code? Is there is something I am missing?

Every time I change the code (changing the urls from dummy page, to facebook, or some other page), I reload the extension.

Comment: facebook.com redirects to www.facebook.com . Not sure but the missing www. could be an issue or perhaps it should be http://*.facebook.com if it accepts wildcards

Comment: Oh my God. Thank you. That was the problem, indeed.

Comment: Now something strange happens. When i reload the facebook page, it works. but when i view a profile (or some other activity) and i click on the Facebook home button (upper left corner), the content is visible again, and it goes hidden only if i f5 the page